# Can not call the method in model to the controller of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is the method in my Model :

```
 public IList<Customer> GetProfileCustomer(int id)
    {
        var list_customer = from c in DataContext.Customers
                            where c.ID == id
                            select c;
        return list_customer.ToList();
    }
```

And this is what I did in my controller :

```
   public ActionResult ShowProfile()
    {
        List<CustomerModels> cus = new List<CustomerModels>();

        return View();
    }
```

I created the object cus to call the method GetProfileCustomer() in the model, but I cannot do that. When I write : cus.GetProfileCustomer, It is error.

Comment: can you provide the error details?

Comment: you need to call GetProfileCustomer on model object not on the list object

Comment: Can you tell me clearly, what should I do that? Thanks.

Comment: i guess your model name is Customer...so you need to use an object of Customer model. such as customer.GetProfileCustomer(id)....but my advise will be to move GetProfileCustomer method in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your major issue is the line:

```
List<CustomerModels> cus = new List<CustomerModels>();
```

That is not creating an instance of `CustomerModels`, so you can't call that method on it. You would have to do something like:

```
public ActionResult ShowProfile()
{
    cus = new CustomerModels();
    var data = cus.GetProfileCustomer(123);
    return View(data);
}
```

---

*However*, in the MVC sense, I don't think loading data from your Model is really the right approach. Typically the Controller has some reference to something else that loads and saves data. The Model is usually just a class with properties to hold the data.

I would look at the "[NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)" sample project. For example, in these files:

- [DinnersController.cs](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70027#874270) (controller)
- [Dinner.cs](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70027#874246) (model)

Note that `DinnersController` holds a reference to a dinner repository, which is the thing that queries the database.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to create instance of `CustomerModels` instead of `List<CustomerModels>`.

```
public ActionResult ShowProfile()
    {
        CustomerModels cus=new CustomerModels(); 
        var list=cus.GetProfileCustomer(1); // 1 is value of ID
        return View(list);
    }
```

You can iterate Model in view (Razor)

```
  <div>
        @foreach(var cust in Model){
            <br /><b>ID :</b> @cust.CustomerID
             }
    </div>
```

ASPX markup

```
<div>
      <% foreach (var cust in Model)
         { %>

         <br />ID : <%:cust.CustomerID %>

      <% } %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you tell me, how can I call this controller in my view?

Comment: @socheata - Take a look at post. You have to pass "list" via View(list) argument.

Answer (score 0):

AVD is right,
You will need to first instantiate the class that houses the GetProfileCustomer method i.e:

```
public ActionResult ShowProfile(int id)
{
    var model = new WhateverTheClassNameIs().GetProfileCustomer(id);

    return View(model);
}
```